# Print cliques using R igraph library

Tags: r, printing, igraph, clique

I want to print cliques for a graph using igraph of R package. The format of data I want to print as 
A B C (showing this data in Res1, Res2, Res3 format...)

Data:
Res1    Res2    Weight
A   B   10
A   C   1
C   B   10
S   B   1
L   A   2

```
library(igraph)
file <- read.table("GraphDemo.net", header=TRUE)
graph <- graph.data.frame(file,  directed=F)
Cliq <- cliques(graph, min = 3, max = NULL)
```

If we want to print the Cliq on the terminal

> Cliq

[[1]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A C B

Which is all very good. But if we want to print to file:

```
write.table(t(Cliq), file="demo.dat",sep = "\t",quote=F,row.names = FALSE)
```

But the result from file is: 
V1
c(1, 2, 5)

I want to print data as just the node names 
A B C. 
What is the way out guys..!!

Answer (score 3):

Use `as_ids()` to convert the igraph.vs object to a vector of names. You can them compile these into a list and export as you see fit.

Try:

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10,0.5,type="gnp",directed=F)
cliq<-cliques(g,min=3)
V(g)$name <- c("a","b", "c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
#Here's the function that will get the vertex names
names <- lapply(1:length(cliq), function(x) as_ids(cliq[[x]]))
```

Now, this extracts all the cliques. If you are interested in only clique of size 3, e.g., you can restrict that using the `cliques()` call or the `lapply()` function.